# Adding HTMLOptGroup dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently adding options to a select element dynamically like this:

```
   const jobs = [{...},{...},{...}];
   const jobsInput = document.querySelector(...);

   jobs.forEach(job => {
        const option = new Option(`${job.title}`, job.id);
        jobsInput.add(option, undefined);
    });
```

I'd like to be able to add an `<optgroup>` each time a property of the job object (`job.companyName`) changes. Pretty sure the logic behind that is easy enough, but I don't know the syntax. Mozilla talks of an [HTMLOptGroupElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptGroupElement), but I don't know how to use it. When I try I get an `illegal constructor` error.

I'd have thought you add it like this:

```
const optGroup = new HTMLOptGroupElement('title');
jobsInput.add(optGroup);
optGroup.label = 'title';
```

but obviously I'm just making this up and it doesn't work :) I can't find anything explaining how to implement the element. If I had to guess it's because it's an interface, but that still doesn't help me

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use forEach and a simple if.

Just need to keep the current group available - when you append, the group is replaced

HTMLOptGroupElement is created using `document.createElement("optgroup");`

```js
const jobs = [
{"companyName":"BMW","title":"Director","id":"1"},
{"companyName":"BMW","title":"Service desk","id":"2"},
{"companyName":"Honda","title":"VP","id":"3"},
{"companyName":"Honda","title":"VP1","id":"4"},
{"companyName":"Honda","title":"VP2","id":"5"},
{"companyName":"Fiat","title":"VP","id":"6"},
{"companyName":"Fiat","title":"VP1","id":"7"},
{"companyName":"Fiat","title":"VP2","id":"8"}
];

const sel = document.getElementById("jobSelect");
jobs.forEach(job => {
  let group = sel.querySelector(`optgroup[label="${job.companyName}"]`);
  if (!group) {
    group = document.createElement("optgroup");
    group.label = job.companyName;
  }
  const opt = new Option(job.title, job.id);
  opt.classList.add("colored"); // may not actually do anything in some browsers
  group.append(opt)
  sel.appendChild(group)
})
```

```css
.colored{ color: red; }
```

```html
<select id="jobSelect"></select>
```

Chrome 100 Windows 10 Enterprise

[image]

Chrome 100 OSX

[image]

Comment: weird, I did thank you for your answer, but it seems to have been removed... so thanks! also, if you don't mind, is it possible to set a class name on the options? `setAttribute` and `.className` don't seem to have worked...

Comment: @NickW you can definitely set a class name to an option element as you would do for every other html elements (it inherits all properties and methods of the HTMLElement interface), eg. `const opt = document.createElement('option');` and `opt.classList.add('someclass');`

Comment: Well.. it does work actually. The class is added, and the css applies (tested on Chrome, Firefox & Opera). https://imgur.com/a/B2E4OT5

Comment: I do not see it work here (Chrome OSX). But if it works for you, great

Comment: Considering DOM manipulations among many other things, Chrome/[V8](https://v8.dev/) works seamlessly accross all devices. So let's say you are acting in good faith, check your chrome version, or just try with any other browser on any device and you will see that it works - if you want to. Also, what makes you think that "_options normally do not have classes_" ? Just read the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement), maybe you don't see that either, it says the _HTMLOptionElement inherits all properties and methods from its parent, HTMLElement_.

Comment: I know but options are normally rendered as a native select and I do not expect everything to work, like in older days one could not hide an option. Also as I said, the options are not red for me in Chrome 100 on OSX

Comment: Yet the fact that we don't _see_ the options in red on a specific system does not mean the class is not added to the element. The OP ask "_is it possible to set a class name on the options?_" the answer is yes, you answered no, "_options normally do not have classes_" which is completely wrong. Relying on a css rule being applied or not is off-topic here.

Comment: And what I meant was "Across web development, most people do not give options classes because they do not work consistently across platforms and browsers" If you want to style an option, use a widget like select2

Comment: For some reason I wasn't getting the notifications for this, but appreciate the input. Eitherway, my problem is one of styling options, and I decided to make a custom select option, which has been... interesting? I'm currently having fun selecting options that are duplicates but under different option groups - but I think that's for another question! If you see it, would appreciate your input as you've both helped my understanding a lot. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You should use :

```
 const optGroup = document.createElement('optgroup');
```

which actually returns an `HTMLOptGroupElement`.

The `Illegal constructor` error happens because `HTMLOptGroupElement` is an interface you can't instanciate by itself (by invoking a constructor with the new keyword), as abstract classes in general for most OO languages.

It is usually preferred to use `document.createElement` instead of constructors for consistency, because not all HTMLElements have a constructor whereas this method is the generic way to create any HTML element.

Also, note that each option (use `document.createElement('option')` as well) must be added to its repective optGroup (parent) element, and the optGroups to the parent select element.